# Does using svn update is a good method for staging server

Tags: svn

I have a staging server which is used to test the functionality before the production is updated. Instead of using the svn export each time to update the svn code, i am using stage as  the working copy of the repo. now every time i need to check something commited in repo i run svn update in stage and i am ready to go.

I want to know is it the right thing to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the best practices in [continuous integration (CI)](http://martinfowler.com/articles/continuousIntegration.html). In order to get quick feedback on whether code changes have introduced any bugs you quickly update the code on a continuous integration server (which you call "staging server") and run a short suite of smoke tests. This allows people to see quickly (10-20min) if they need to fix anything.

However, another best practice is to do a clean checkout of the code base once a day (usually at night) and run a longer suite of tests (feature tests, stress tests, etc.). It can be done on the same or different CI server.

The important thing (as @YusufX mentions) that these things **must** be done automatically. For that you should use a Continuous Integration server. There are several available. Personally, I am a big fan of [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) (it's free and Open Source).

Answer (score 1):

If no one else is using stage, then that works. Otherwise, you should put it in a dev-test server first. Regardless, auto-deploy and then auto-test is the "right thing to do".